# How to call tabular function inside the for loop

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have one table with 3 columns.

1. id
2. start
3. end

I am applying one function on table , function with 3 arguments.

> Ex:Function1(id,start,end)

This function is working when I pass  static  value  to it.but  I want to run this function on full table.

How to do this?

This my use case Actually

```
datatable(id:string, start:string,end:string)
[
   'Z213',datetime(2021-08-06T02:12:37.1597030Z),datetime(2021-08-06T17:37:21.8962890Z),
  'Z213',datetime(2021-08-06T00:00:25.7896310Z),datetime(2021-08-06T01:59:50.1172850Z),
  'Z213',datetime(2021-08-06T02:04:37.1243340Z),datetime(2021-08-06T02:12:37.1352020Z),
  'Z213',datetime(2021-08-06T17:45:19.7289570Z),datetime(2021-08-06T23:56:44.8047730Z),
  'Z213',datetime(2021-08-06T17:43:23.7238020Z),datetime(2021-08-06T17:43:28.7256000Z),
  'Z213',datetime(2021-08-06T02:04:17.1238770Z),datetime(2021-08-06T02:04:24.1256730Z),
  'Z213',datetime(2021-08-06T02:02:15.1199760Z),datetime(2021-08-06T02:02:15.1204780Z),
]
|invoke function1('Z213',datetime(2021-08-06T02:12:37.1597030Z),datetime(2021-08-06T17:37:21.8962890Z))
```

So when I pass this 1st row then it will work fine .

but I want do this like

```
|invoke Function (id,start,end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [tabular functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#invoking-a-user-defined-function) here is an example:

```
let append_to_column_a=(T:(a:string), what:string) {
    T | extend a=strcat(a, " ", what)
};
datatable (a:string) ["sad", "really", "sad"]
| invoke append_to_column_a(":-)")
```